# Cancel loading of another Javascript file on the page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

If I have a script that's being loaded on my page that I can't remove (this is a very large enterprise application, the code has since been lost/buried), is there a way to cancel the script from being loaded/executed by the browser?

Some example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <!-- Automatically added to every page, can't be removed from the backend -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyBadScriptFile.js"></script>

    <!-- Other scripts being loaded, i.e. jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- My script file that I have control over -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyScriptCanceller.js"></script>

  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

My question is, what can I put in `MyScriptCanceller.js` that will prevent the browser from loading or executing `MyBadScriptFile.js`?

Edit: Or is there some other way of manipulating the response to where this script can be removed/disabled at any point?

Comment: could you delete or empty the file? could you block it with your web server?

Comment: @DanielA.White No, I do not have access to the file at all. It is embedded in a compiled application on the back-end.

Comment: please elaborate on your environment.

Comment: Environment is ASP.NET Forms / .NET 4 (Fixed tags as such).

Comment: could you tell iis not to serve the file?

Comment: It's an embedded resource (comes back as an `.ashx`). So, no, because that would disable all the other Javascript we've registered that *isn't* bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Javascript files are run in order. This means that the contents of the third file won't be executed until the contents of the first and second files have been executed. And once code has been executed, you can't undo it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an application/plugin like firebug to locate where on the page the script is being loaded from, and comment out the script (if it cannot be removed).

Having another script will never cancel the loading of the the previously initiated script, unless it is loaded asynchronously (AJAX). If fact, it will only add to the load-time, albeit not by very much if it is a small file.

It may be a bit of work, but I think your best bet is still to search and locate the original long-loading script's location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, nobody will ever need the javascript, why not commenting out/emptying the source?
So, the file would be loaded, but it wouldn't have any further effects? If you haven't any access to the source a bruteforce attempt would be to intercept the html-delivery process and preprocess the html to strip out the unwanted javascript or to reverse engineer the compiled code.

P.S.: As I saw from your comments - you have no access to the source. That makes it difficult.

Comment: You are correct.. To OP: But if you do not have access to the source code, how would you add `<script type="text/javascript" src="MyScriptCanceller.js"></script> ` to the HTML file?? Please make me understand.. Confused..

Comment: Because the script is embedded in a compiled assembly that we don't have the source for anymore. Source code can exist without the ability for you to edit it.

Comment: In what language was it written? Thought of a decompiler?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could have MyScriptCanceller.js dynamically create your third link if some condition is met? If the condition is not met, it just won't create the third js file from being called.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: The first script is "automatically added to every page, can't be removed from the backend"

Comment: But if you do not have access to the source code, how would you add <script type="text/javascript" src="MyScriptCanceller.js"></script> to the HTML file??